# Can I build public cloud using bare metal servers?

Tags: cloud, cloud-computing, bare-metal

Can I build a public cloud using bare metal servers, hypervisor? If not, what is the procedure to become a public cloud provider in the most cost-effective method ?

Comment: Of course it's possible. But if you have to ask these questions you are not really in a position to try.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with that. I am new to this domain and need proper guidance. Let me know about the resources I have to refer

Comment: At the end of the day, all public clouds are built on bare metal servers.

Comment: How do you think every other cloud provider is building his cloud? Hint: At the end every virtual machine runs on bare metal. Tiem to learn basics, is it not?

Comment: You all need to chillax! Everyone starts somewhere! Public cloud infrastructure is so complicated these days that it EASY for even experienced sysadmins to get lost in the woods. That's why "devops" been popping up to account for such. Please, let's be a little more sensible okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct a public cloud is composed of *at least one but usually a fleet of bare metal machines*.

What's you need at the base is truly what sorta of cloud you are expecting to offer. Examples includes typical VPS clouds where you charge an hourly rate for the VPSes and offer "cloud" features like cloud based firewalls, load balancers, etc. Think Vultr, Linode, Digital Ocean, UpCloud, etc.

Another instance is HA Clouds, think on platforms like GCP and AWS. These is gonna be more complicated since you need to employ *distributed* infrastructure at every point (SANs, hypervisors, switches, etc). *Since NO downtime is acceptable* and you are expected to offer Service Level Agreements (SLAs) to match. In order to stand behind such offerings. You can however rack in quite a bit considering to compensate the people hours and complexity required.

If your just starting out, you might wanna pick up a hourly/daily Bare Metal Rental and toy around with a hypervisor until you get the hang of it and feel for what you wanna do from there.